# Dynamically loading a region inside a region only loads first time backbone marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I've got a marionette region called overlay in a project.

Inside the view that loads inside that overlay, are some other regions.

When I trigger the overlay the first time, it works perfectly.

When I close the overlay and open it again, the overlay itself comes up, but inner CollectionViews don't load into regions correctly?

Any ideas why this would work first time, but not any time after that?

I feel it's something to do with removing a region div, and then when it is shown again, the region needs to be rebound as existing.

This is an example of the controller code -

```
Manager.module("ManagerDiscovery",function(ManagerDiscovery,Manager,Backbone,Marionette,$,_){
ManagerDiscovery.showDiscovery = function(){
    ManagerDiscovery.Admin.overlayShowing = true;
    var discoveryOverlayView = new ManagerDiscovery.DiscoveryOverlayView();
    Manager.overlayRegion.show(discoveryOverlayView);

    ajaxUtils.sendGet("/channels/getPublicManager", null, function(response){
        ManagerDiscovery.managerCollection = new ManagerDiscovery.ManagerCollection(response);

        var managerDiscoveryListView = new ManagerDiscovery.ManagerDiscoveryCollectionView({
            collection : ManagerDiscovery.managerCollection
        });
        Manager.overlayContentRegion.show(managerDiscoveryListView);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: So your overlayContentRegion is actually a region on discoveryOverlayView correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm considering just making the overlay a normal piece of html that I hide/show as needed, and then paint into the regions using marionette. Means the regions shouldn't appear disappear from the the DOM, but felt a bit odd as it works first time.

Comment: Yes, but when you close a marionette region is closes the view within it and all views withing that etc. If you want to reshow it, you need to re-insert the managerDiscoveryListView each time. I'm guessing that the handle to your Manager.overlayContentRegion is the culprit here

Comment: try discoveryOverlayView.overlayContentRegion.show(managerDiscoveryListView) so you know you're adding the listView to the correct instance of discoveryOverlayView

Comment: Just got Cannot call method 'show' of undefined which I think makes sense, as I don't quite get how you could reference an inner region from a view, without binding it at some point? Maybe there is some kind of region bind I can do after the first view has been shown, but then, why does it work the first time?

Comment: Can you show me how you are assigning Manager.overlayContentRegion?

Comment: The region is assigned at the start, after the app is created. var Manager = new Marionette.Application(); Manager.addRegions({ overlayContentRegion : "#overlay-content-region"});